# How to update from v12.0 to v12.2

Tags: angular

I had recently updated from v11 to v12 following the update guide. At the time `ng update ...@12` got me `v12.0`. I have just noticed we are now up to `v12.2.x` and there is no update guide for `12.0` to `12.2`.

Should I use `npm install` after manually updating the `package.json` file or should I use the `ng update` command with the parameters `@angular/core@12.2` and `@angular/cli@12.2`?

Answer (score 0):

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/updating) suggest to use `ng update`

Comment: Use `ng update` as a guide, only part of your update process. Then manually update packages. Also try using NCU https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates helps a LOT!

Comment: For simple updates, the CLI command `ng update` is all you need

Comment: It's failed me every time.